# Applying a font (a code) to all parts of a widget in css

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I want to apply a piece of code (for example, a specific font) to all parts of a widget
What selector or what should I call to be able to do this?

In the following code snippet, the font is applied to the selectors and part of the comments, but when a new comment is registered in the comments section of the site, the previous font is displayed again for the new comment.

```
/* Widget post comments */
.elementor-element-3d8990cd .elementor-widget-post-comments{
    font-family:'IRANSansWeb_FaNum';
    
}
.elementor-element-3d8990cd .elementor-widget-post-comments{
    font-family:'IRANSansWeb_FaNum';
}

/* Wpdiscuz sort button active */
.wpd-thread-filter .wpdf-sorting .wpdiscuz-sort-button-active{
    font-family:'IRANSansWeb_FaNum';
}
```

Comment: _"but when a new comment is registered in the comments section of the site, the previous font is displayed again for the new comment."_ - then it probably got inserted in a place, where those selectors don't match. That's all we can tell you based on being given nothing more than those snippets of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [[attribute*=value] CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.php) in this case.

```
/* Widget post comments */
div[class*="elementor-element-"] .elementor-widget-post-comments{
    font-family:'IRANSansWeb_FaNum'; 
}

/* Wpdiscuz sort button active */
.wpd-thread-filter .wpdf-sorting .wpdiscuz-sort-button-active{
    font-family:'IRANSansWeb_FaNum';
}
```

You can also add a specific common comment parent class with `div` if needed.

Comment: thanks
Unfortunately, I am not familiar with css and html code
Is it possible to give advice on how to use your advice in the code above?
What does the piece of code that does this look like?

Thank you

Comment: In simple words `[class*="elementor-element-"]` means match a selector that contains class `elementor-element-`, since each comment ID is unique hence we are trying to match and find the selector with the CSS class prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much
I finally solved this problem with your help, my dear friend
How simple it was
Be more successful and healthier than yesterday

Answer (score 0):

you can use the body element tag to apply font on every part of element as we should write the code of element in body only.
The code written in body element (css) will be applied to every part of the body code and used to write background color so that it can be applied to whole page and used to write font size and family etc using css in style tag in  head part.

```
using
```

`<style> body{ font-size=34px;} </style>`